# Visual Studio 2013 SDK on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-10

For some reason the setup is blocked when trying to install VS2013 SDK on a Windows 10 machine.

Any ideas?

[image]

Here is a relevant part of the log file:

```
[5EB4:710C][2015-03-27T11:22:50]i052: Condition 'CompatibilityMode = 0' evaluates to true.
[5EB4:710C][2015-03-27T11:22:50]i052: Condition 'NOT((VersionNT > v6.1) OR (VersionNT = v6.1 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1))' evaluates to false.
[5EB4:710C][2015-03-27T11:22:50]i052: Condition '( NOT ((ProCheck_ProfessionalCore_DetectKey = 1) OR (ProCheck_VSCore_DetectKey = 1)) ) AND (CurrentOperation = "Install") ' evaluates to false.
[5EB4:710C][2015-03-27T11:22:50]i000: MUX:  Stop Block: CompatibilityMode : Windows Program Compatibility mode is on. Turn it off and then try Setup again.
```

Comment: FYI I have tried to run it as compat mode for Windows 8, etc, but no luck.

Comment: As of the time of writing this comment the issue is still persistent.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found a way to install it. First, you should unpack the installer using command line:

```
vssdk_full.exe /layout
```

Choose a folder where you want the files to be extracted. Then press the “Download” button. Go to that folder and start the installer. It will bypass the check and install the SDK.

Comment: It's bizarre that this works, because the extracted `vssdk_full.exe` is bitwise-identical to the original `vssdk_full.exe`, but it works!

Answer (score 3):

It does not look like it is supported on Windows 10 (yet).

[Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=40758)

> **Supported Operating System**
>
> Windows 7 Service Pack 1, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: VS2013 works fine after upgrading from Windows 8.1 to 10, but I am having trouble on a fresh install of Windows 10.

Comment: the above link redirected to MS website with 404, I also tried to Google around and the result is same. any help?

Answer (score 3):

I've got the same error.

Have you renamed the installer? Because I did, so I won't work until you rename it again to vssdk_full.exe.

Comment: These days, when downloading it from MSDN, the file is named "en_visual_studio_2013_sdk_x86_3009047.exe" by MS themselves!!! Renaming it to "vssdk_full.exe" solves the problem. I can't believe this.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2013 require .Net 3.5 so, you need to install .Net framework 3.5 first, then block will be remove

Comment: This not make any difference.

Comment: I have same problem and i installed visual studio in my window 10 machine

You can see this image [link](http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/0561/cct6bs1lpb2w9cfzg.jpg?size_id=8)

Answer (score 0):

One common cause of this problem is that Windows' built-in compatibility modes kick in (or don't) because of what seem like minor problems such as the setup executable not having the file name Windows is looking for.

For example, there are scenarios where a user has downloaded the setup package twice which leads to two different executables: `vssdk_full.exe` and `vssdk_full (1).exe`. If you launch the latter, you may run into the type of problem described in this thread. The easiest fix is to make it so Windows recognizes the filename but getting rid of the `(1)` suffix.